# Select Weekly/Bi-weekly/twice a week in multidatespicker

Tags: jquery-multidatespicker

i'm not sure if this is possible but i can't find any clue of doing this with multidatespicker..
i'm creating a web booking system which need to allow customer to select any booking date which they like.
But now my client was requesting to create package like weekly package(4 times per month), biweekly(1 times per 2 weeks) and etc..For weekly example.. when customer choose tuesday of that week.. the rest of 6 days all will be disable.. and for biweekly.. for that week and next week will be disable..

Thousand appreciate for someone who could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: in my booking project the user must can select days range but also week range (only from Saturday to Saturday).

I managed the selection of the week on onSelect() event of multiDatesPicker() init function: by click on a day of the week MultiDatesPicker auto-select the relative week from Saturday to Saturday.

Unfortunately, for me the open issue is the hover event, because I want MultiDatesPicker also hover the week by pass hover the days of a week, not only select it, so the user could have perception to really choose weeks, not days.
It's singular that MultiDatesPicker has not a onHover() function to manage the "pre-selection"/hover event.

```
var autoselectRange = [0, days_range];

$('.multidatespicker-wrapper').multiDatesPicker({
numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
minDate: 1, 
firstDay: 1,
mode: 'daysRange',
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

    var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

    from_date = new Date(moment(dateText, "MM/DD/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    to_date = new Date (moment(dateText, "MM/DD/YYYY").add('days', days_range - 1).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

    if (weekRange) {
        // Setting of Start and End of the week
        if (from_date.getDay() == 6) numDaysToWeekStart = 0; // because Saturday in this case it is Start of the week
        else numDaysToWeekStart = from_date.getDay() + 1;

        from_date = new Date(from_date.setDate(from_date.getDate() - numDaysToWeekStart));
        to_date = new Date(to_date.setDate(to_date.getDate() - numDaysToWeekStart));

        // Setting of the days of the week
        date = new Date(from_date); 
        weeks = [];

        while (date <= to_date) {
            weeks.push(new Date(date));
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }

        // Selection of the days of the week/weeks in MDP Calendar
        $(this).multiDatesPicker('resetDates', 'picked');
        $(this).multiDatesPicker('addDates', weeks);
    }

    // Any more controls

},   
autoselectRange: autoselectRange,
pickableRange: days_range,

// any more settings });
```

I hope It could be a help; if you have some idea to manage hover event and you can share it. Thanks